# Alguém sabe como solucionar o Erro: "Failed to lookup view" no nodeJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js

Minha pastas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O arquivo "admin.js" contém as minhas rotas:

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

router.get('/', (req,res)=>{
    res.render("admin/index")
})

router.get('/posts',(req,res)=>{

})

router.get('/categorias',(req,res)=>{
    res.send("aaaaaaaaa")
})

module.exports = router
```

O arquivo "App.js"

```
const express = require('express')
    const  handlebars = require('express-handlebars')
    const bodyParcer =  require('body-parser')
    const app = express()
    const admin = require('./routes/admin')
    const path = require('path')
    //const  mongoose = require('mongoose')


    //Body Parcer
        app.use(bodyParcer.urlencoded({extended:true}))
        app.use(bodyParcer.json())

    //HandleBars

        app.engine('handlebars', handlebars({defaultLayout: 'main'}))
       app.set('view engine', 'handlebars')


    //Mongoose


    //Public
        app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,"public")))
//Rotas

app.use('/admin',admin)



const PORT = 8080
app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log(`Servidor Rodando na porta ${PORT} ...`))
```

Quando eu tento acessar a url "http://localhost:8080/admin/" para acessar o arquivo "index.handlebars" que está na pasta "views/admin", ocorre o seguinte erro:

```
Error: Failed to lookup view "admin/index" in views directory "C:\workspaceN\BlogApp\views"
```

Comment: se você reparar na imagem vai ver que o seu esta escrito "index.hadlebars" e o certo seria "index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pela descrição do erro, não está localizando o caminho admin/index porque ele está dentro da pasta views, teria que informar este caminho. Acima da linha onde você ativa o app.engine('handlebars'), vocêpode colocar o seguinte:

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
```

Aqui tem um tutorial que explica a configuração do handlebars

https://www.oodlestechnologies.com/blogs/How-To-Use-Handlebars-in-Node-JS